# Gradle build failing after update to 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've recently updated the gradle version of my project from 2.14.1 to 3.0. Since then the gradle build is failing every time with this error:

> Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I've searched google and found some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059655/strange-gradle-error-android-studio) one but nothing is working. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of plugin are you using?

Comment: The latest stable gradle plugin (**2.1.3**) works with [Gradle 2.14.1 or higher][1] but doesn't support the Gradle 3.x.

  [1]: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: it says Gradle 2.14.1 or higher which doesn't really exclude 3.x versions?

Comment: You can try to use the latest beta version : 2.2.0-beta2 but I don't know if it is supported.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Upgrade your gradle build tools to the latest version.

One easy way to do this is to add the latest version of the build tools as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file, for example:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
}
```

You can then run `gradle tasks` and gradle will download everything you need.

After Android Studio 2.2 stable released on Sep 19 2016 , the latest version of the build tools is 2.2.0 . So you can fix it by :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

As Android Studio 2.4 stable is not ready to release yet (May 4 2017), the latest stable version of build tools is 2.3.1 .

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
}
```

If you update this build tools version to 2.3.* , you should also update gradle wrapper version to 3.3 in /yourProjectRoot/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file. (i know it is not matching question `Gradle build failing after update to 3.0`, but i strongly suggest you to use latest build tool as google recommended)

BTW: version 2.3.1 of build tool is only exist on jCenter, not MavenCentral, so if you run into error below when run gradlew command line in terminal

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.pom
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.jar
```

just replace mavenCentral() with jcenter() like

```
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    //mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334872/exception-in-thread-main-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-tag-mismatch-react-nativ

Answer (score 29):

**For latest update of Android Studio 3.0**

In `gradle-wrapper.properties`(File Name) change URL of `distributionUrl` to the following:

> `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Comment: This is the Best answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. Just needed to add `google()` along with `jcenter()` repository

Comment: Working For me Thanx (y)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you use gradle plugin 2.1.3, 
It's simple to solve:

> update your gradle plugin to version 2.2.0-beta1

Notes: this is a beta version, maybe you can get any other issues.

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/classcastexception-in-gradle-nightly-3-0-20160609/17979

Happy coding :)

Comment: I am about to kill myself. Thank you for saving my life.

Comment: what if you use 2.3.1?

Comment: nvm --> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'

Answer (score 5):

Okay I got it working. For anyone facing the same problem the way it worked for me is as follows:

1. Go to your external .gradle folder (for me it was C:\Users\drilon.gradle). Inside caches and daemon folder delete all the version folder (they look like this "2.14.1", or "3.0"). Also go to wrapper -> dists -> delete everything there.
2. Inside your project root (for me it was C:\Users\drilon\AndroidStudioProjects\PorjectName) go to the .gradle folder and delete everything there.
3. Rebuild the project

**EDIT:**
Turns out this solution was setting the gradle version back to 2.14.1. ending0421's solution is the working one.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I had to use the solution provided by LinuxArtisan. (upgrade to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1 )

Answer (score 3):

For latest update of **Android Studio 3.3.1** below code work.

1) **gradle-wrapper.properties** add below line.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

2)**build.gradle** in **project level** add below classpath

```
 dependencies
    {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

    }
```

Comment: after adding above code gradle sync code will work like charm.

Answer (score 1):

if your gradle version is: 3.0.1 then use below code in your gradle-wrapper.properties `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

if 3.1.2 then use below code in your gradle-wrapper.properties 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

Answer (score 1):

```
    After 1 hour R&D No Solution as worked for me...

    But still i have solution follow this its work 100%

    step 1: upgrade your build.gradle(Project:<your project name>)
    Example :  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3' // old gradle file
               classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1' // upgraded file 

                                OR
               classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

    Step 2 : Upgrade compileSdkVersion buildToolsVersion 
    Example : compileSdkVersion 23    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3 // old api's
              compileSdkVersion 25    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" // upgraded api's

   Step 3:  upgrade gradle-wrapper.properties 
   Example : distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip // old or any version
            distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip // new or any version
```

Step 4 : finally goto build>rebuild project...

Still You face some problem commit or inbox me....

......End @Ambilpura

Answer (score 1):

You should [check your Gradle Plugin version and Gradle version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) before updating.

**Check Gradle Plugin Version in your project level `build.gradle` file-**

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:gradle.plugin.version'
    }
}
```

**Check Gradle Version in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`-**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-gradle.version.zip
```

At the time of this answer, below were the latest versions. You can match your versions on [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle).

[image: gradleversion]

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete everything inside gradle folder in main project folder and Rebuild the 
project. It will start working.

Answer (score 0):

If your **gradle plugin 3.0.0** for studio version 3.0, Add this in **gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

simple answer try this...

goto build.gradle(PROJECT) and check the gradle version as shown below

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3' or 3.0 or 3.1 or xx.xx

now open gradle-wrapper.properties see this line of code if gradle version is 2.x this the code below...

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

gradle-2.14.1-all.zip line of code must be same as gradle version

example:

example:
mine is 2.x so...
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3' in build.gradle so

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
in gradle-wrapper.properties.

if gradle version is 3.x then
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' in build.gradle then

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.14.1-all.zip
in gradle-wrapper.properties.

check this it will works

Answer (score 0):

if Android Studio Android Studio 3.0 below code work.

gradle-wrapper.properties add below line.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

if  Android Studio Android Studio 3.1.2 below code work.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

if Android Studio 3.3.1 below code work.

1) gradle-wrapper.properties add below line.

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

2) build.gradle in project level add below

```
 dependencies { 
             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Android Gradle dependencies are not working in new update of Android
> Studio

Most important thing if you are face a lot of problems :
It is applicable on plugin 7.1 or new update version
Please Try this:

> Go To -> settings.gradle inside of repositories {  } :

add two files as :

```
maven{ url("https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases/") }
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

The complete structure in

> settings.gradle

file as given below :

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{ url("https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases/") }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MyApp"
include ':app'
```

And last step, it is must be added into gradle.properties files.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```