# Scala build failing in AndroidStudio 2.1.3

Tags: scala, android-studio

After updating to AndroidStudio build 143.3101438, I got the error shown in this ticket:
[Gradle build failing after update to 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034655/gradle-build-failing-after-update-to-3-0)

After following the steps shown to resolve, I get a new error:

Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.scala.ScalaCompileOptions.getForce()Ljava/lang/String;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I've reverted to the a prior build, 143.2821654, and the issue disappears

Comment: Did you try clearing your caches, as indicated? If your caches were built with a previous version there may have been a code regression that isn't a problem when you roll back. Everything in the `.gradle` directory can be deleted safely (assuming you're not actively running it).

Comment: Yes, I did, both the ~/.gradle and the ./project/.gradle.   I was starting with clean install of my os, which is why I was installing the latest android studio. This happened on the first project I imported back in from github.

Comment: And after some android studio updates, it started working again, out of the blue, just like it broke.

Comment: Bizarre! And frustrating when it's for super unclear reasons.