# android studio failed to sync gradle project

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build a cordova app.
But when I try to build it, I get this error message:

> Error:Cause:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I'm actually new to android development, and I'm quite lost.

Hope someone can guide me through this issue.

Comment: Did you try the error message's suggestions? Re-downloading the Gradle dependencies, closing the IDE and killing all Java processes etc?

Comment: Yes, already tried those two. I've rolled back and tried with some different versions of gradle, and still I'm getting that error

Comment: Are you using any third-party plugins? If so, I would recommend trying to remove them one by one and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build failing after update to 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034655/gradle-build-failing-after-update-to-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, from Android project explorer, find gradle-wrapper.properties, open it, change the distributionUrl line, such as following(2.14.1 is just an example):

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Then build again, this may solve this problem.